# Is there any progress on Problem 13 (from Schoen and Yau)?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

This is closed related to the question asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176638/is-there-any-progress-on-problem-12-from-schoen-and-yau). I wonder if there is any progress on Problem 13 from the "Problem Section" in Schoen and Yau, page 281, problem 13, which asks: 
Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be compact Einstein manifolds with negative curvature. Suppose that $\pi_1(M_1)=\pi_1(M_2)$ and $\dim M_1\geq 3$. Is $M_1$ isometric to $M_2$?

Comment: To my knowledge, there has been no progress. Topology of Einstein manifolds is largely a mystery and one can ask many simple sounding questions with no answers in sight.